# Content Download Time for Video Metadata is much more than Image

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, google-chrome-devtools

So I have been trying to generate a thumbnail from a video by using the video tag of HTML5.

I have used it as follows

```
<video preload="metadata">
    <source src="video url">
</video>
```

The time taken to serve the request is around 900ms and what I find strange is there are too many calls, all with status code 206 partial content.

I have checked the content ranges in the headers and what I find unusual is that there's one request with content length equal to size of the file by in the the console the size shows 410 Bytes.

[image: Chrome Console View]

I have compared the results with that of an image of size 19KB. The request is obviously of 19KB but the time taken is 60ms. After analysing the waterfall, I saw the content download time is 10x for video metadata compared to image download.

My Main Questions would therefore be :

- Why there are so many requests ?
- Are those request fetching the metadata of the video, given
  preload=metadata is set?
- Why content download time is more in case of video metadata?

I have tried a lot to find the answers, but could not find much help.

Comment: If the mp4 file wasn't produced as streaming-friendly (more info can be found in the documentation for various mp4 muxing tools), Chrome might have to prefetch the entire file to be able to get the metadata.

Comment: If that would have been the case, then the download size would equal to the file size which is around 10mb. I wonder what is the 410B, 32.3KB and 414B of download that chrome is initiating

Comment: A non-streamable MP4 can have its index section at the end of file which is what Chrome fetches. A streamable MP4 uses interleaving so Chrome would be able to load only the beginning of a file.

Comment: But that doesn't account for the random request that chrome sends right ? In two cases its in bytes and in one case its some KB's. Also for a different video number of request could be more than 3 or sometimes its just 1. And also the time, its taking too much time to download data in order of bytes. Why does that happen

Comment: If a file is not streaming-friendly, Chrome will have to poke at some known locations (like at the end of file) to find where to look for the metadata. Not sure why keep guessing - simply inspect the MP4 file in a utility that checks streamability or remux it as I suggested.